# no me carga el segundo combo en php postgres

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

tengo una duda, no me carga el segundo combo, cuando selecciono en el primer combo el segundo me aparece vacío.

Estoy usando una sola tabla en `postgresql` y a partir de eso quiero seleccionar distintos campos en el combo y después que me muestre la consulta generada.

En la tabla viene year, control, elementos, entonces en el primer combo selecciono año, en el segundo control y en el tercero elemento. no puse la `url` en `ajax` porque solo estoy trabajando en este archivo `index.php`, no llamo ningún otro archivo. Cómo lo soluciono o habrá otra solución y no hacer eso?

Gracias

Este es mi código

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title>Test</title>
</head>

<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '5432';
$database = 'posts';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = '';

$cnx = pg_connect('host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password);

 $qr = "select * from vw_dhqc_report";
 $year = 'year';
 $id_control = 'id_control';
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<h3>Seleccione una Opci&oacute;n<h3>
<select name="year" id="year_id">
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<?php
$query = "select distinct $year from vw_dhqc_report";
$result = pg_query($query);

while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$fila['year']."'>".$fila['year']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="id_control" id="control_id">
<option value="0">Seleccionar</option>

<?php
$query2 = "select distinct id_control  from vw_dhqc_report WHERE  year = $_POST[$year]";
$result2 = pg_query($query2);
while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result2)){
echo "<option value='".$fila['id_control']."'>".$fila['id_control']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="element" id="element_id" >
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<?php

$query3 = "select distinct element from vw_dhqc_report WHERE  year = $_POST[$year] AND id_control= $_POST[$id_control]";
$result3 = pg_query($query3);

while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result3)){
echo "<option value='".$fila['element']."'>".$fila['element']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

 <?php 
// if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
//  echo 'year: '.$_POST['year']; 
// echo 'id_control: '.$_POST['id_control']; 
//  echo 'ELement: '.$_POST['element']; 
//  } 
 ?> 

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#year_id').on('change', function(){
        var year = $(this).val();
        if(year){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'year='+year,
                success:function(result){
                    $('#control_id').html(result);   
                            $('#element_id').html('<option value="">Select id_control</option>'); 
                //             for (var i = 0; i >= result.length; i++) {
                // $("#control_id").append("<option value='" + result[i]["id_control"] + "'>" + result[i]["id_control"] + "</option>");

              }   

            }); 
        }else{
            $('#control_id').html('<option value="">Select year</option>');
            $('#element_id').html('<option value="">Select id_control</option>'); 
        }
    });
       $('#control_id').on('change', function(){
        var id_control = $(this).val();
        // alert(id_control);
        if(id_control){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'id_control='+id_control,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#element_id').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#element_id').html('<option value="">Select id_control</option>'); 
        }
     });
});
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, según puedo ver en tu código no  estas haciendo el llamado de ajax otro **script** sino desde la misa pagina. Lo que te puede estar sucediendo es que la variable de **html** este vacía, por lo que el  **success** no esta de volviendo el resultado (`success:function(html){
                    $('#element_id').html(html);
                }`).

Comment: si de hecho no me devuelve nada, como lo puedo solucionar, me seria de gran ayuda gracias, apenas estoy empezando con javascript

Comment: ademas en la URL no puse nada porque estoy trabajando en el mismo archivo y no hago llamado a ningun otro, o que deberia poner alli , ya que todo lo estoy haciendo en un solo archivo index.php

Comment: Si pasa la variable vasia te cambia el estado del combo que tienes lleno desde el php. Lo que pueden hacer es que coloques el contenido del combo 2 en un script aparte ese lo llamas con ajax y asi vas a poder llenar su valor.

Comment: separar la  consulta en otro script para el combo 2 ?  y despues llamarlo en ajax ?

Comment: No los datos que tienes dentro de la etiqueta select del segundo combo, pasalo a un script y ese script lo  llamas con ajax el resultado que te imprime con el **echo** es el que te va a llenar la variable del **succes** que en tu caso es html

Comment: no entiendo amigo, disculpa

Comment: me puedes mostrar un ejemplo ?  porfavor ya llevo dias con esto y no he solucionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te esta sucediendo, es que la variable **html** que estas llenado el segundo combo esta vacía. Lo que tienes que hacer es llamar desde otro script la información, a continuación te dejo un ejemplo para el combo 2:

**Nota:** el nombre del **script** del segundo combo se llama **control.php** si le vas a a colocar otro nombre tienes que cambiarlo en el **url** del ajax. También te recomiendo que sino tienes resulta por algún error, descomenta la linea que esta dentro del **suscces** comentada y ahí te debe de mostrar los que esta pasando en el script externo también con f12 puedes ver errores que se te produzcan en el javascript.Refresca o borra los datos del cache del navegador.

Gracias

**En la pagina:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title>Test</title>
</head>

<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '5432';
$database = 'posts';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = '';

$cnx = pg_connect('host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password);

 $qr = "select * from vw_dhqc_report";
 $year = 'year';
 $id_control = 'id_control';
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<h3>Seleccione una Opci&oacute;n<h3>
<select name="year" id="year_id">
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<?php
$query = "select distinct $year from vw_dhqc_report";
$result = pg_query($query);

while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$fila['year']."'>".$fila['year']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="id_control" id="control_id">
<option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

 <?php 
// if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
//  echo 'year: '.$_POST['year']; 
// echo 'id_control: '.$_POST['id_control']; 
//  echo 'ELement: '.$_POST['element']; 
//  } 
 ?> 

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#year_id').on('change', function(){
        var year = $(this).val();
        if(year){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'year='+year,
                url: 'control.php',  
                success:function(data){
                    //alert(data);   
                    $('#control_id').html(data);   
              }   

            }); 
        }else{
            $('#control_id').html('<option value="">Select year</option>');
        }
    });
});
  </script>
</html>
```

**Cargamos el contenido del segundo combo.**

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '5432';
$database = 'posts';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = '';

$cnx = pg_connect('host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password);

$query2 = "select distinct id_control  from vw_dhqc_report WHERE  year = $_POST[$year]";
$result2 = pg_query($query2);
while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result2)){
echo "<option value='".$fila['id_control']."'>".$fila['id_control']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ya lo reviso

Comment: De nada solo espero que te sirva cual quier cosa me la dejas saber.

Comment: si gracias cualquier cosa te aviso

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: note: { opened at line 27, column 19       me marca ese error pero no tiene errores alli y cuando comente el codigo javascript ajax, se pierde el error no se a que se deba

Comment: ya se soluciono gracias

Comment: Que bien que ya se soluciono y que era el error me alegra que te allá servido mi explicación. Gracias

Comment: era una coma que faltaba en la url de javascript

Comment: hola una pregunta amigo y para mostrar las consultas generadas  al seleccionar los combos, quiero ver las consultas, creo otro script? gracias

Comment: Si tienes que hacer el mismo procedimiento por cada combo que quieras colocar en cascada en la forma en que tienes hecho tu código si.

Comment: lo que quiero es que me muestre la consulta de los dos combos seleccionados  ejemplo   select distinct id_control,year from vw_dhqc_report where year= $year;   y ya al darli clic me muestre en una tabla la consulta seleccionada de los dos combos

Comment: Mira si puedes formula una pregunta con lo que tienes y lo que quieres lograr por que no te logro entender lo que quieres hacer

Comment: gracias ya lo resolvi y gracias por ayudarme

Comment: hola amigo y cuando quiero agregar un tercer combo?

Comment: este es mi script      $('#element_id').on('change', function(){
        var id_element = $(this).val();
        // alert(id_control);
        if(resultado){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'consulta_reporte.php',
                data:'element_id='+id_element,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#resultado').html(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#resultado').html('<div value="">Mostrar Tabla</div>');
        }
     });
    });       no me trae los datos que quiero ver

Comment: El combo 3 esta anidado con el de control

Comment: ok gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: hola amigo viste mi publicacion que subi recientemente?, me puedes ayudar porfavor es sobre mostrar la grafica despus de seleccionar tres combos pero no me pinta me aparece undefined, gracias